# Unable to apply sorting in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to apply sorting in my MVC 5 application. I used the code [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
to apply sorting. Unfortunately, its not working and it won't sort. Am I missing something? All datatypes I used are strings btw.

Here is the code:

```
//Controller
public ActionResult Index(string sort)
        {
            ViewBag.ExtSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) ? "ext_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DtsSortParm = sort == "DTS" ? "dts_desc" : "DTS";
            var sales = from s in db.Sales1 select s;
            switch (sort)
            {
                case "ext_desc":
                    sales = sales.OrderByDescending(s => s.ExtSerial);
                    break;                
                case "DTS":
                    sales = sales.OrderBy(s => s.DTS);
                    break;
                case "dts_desc":
                    sales = sales.OrderByDescending(s => s.DTS);
                    break;
                default:
                    sales = sales.OrderBy(s => s.ExtSerial);
                    break;
            }
            return View(db.Sales1.ToList());            
        }
```

And my View applied:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ExtSerial", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ExtSortParm })
 @Html.ActionLink("DTS", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DtsSortParm })
```

Was there something I missed? DTS is a date by the way just in string type. Here is an example value: 5/11/2015 5:29:56 AM

db is my database & Sales1 is my SalesEntity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting your collection but he following line returns the original unsorted collection

```
return View(db.Sales1.ToList());
```

You need to return the sorted collection to the view using

```
return View(sales.ToList());
```